# How do I get String-value from jdbc sampler to INT value in other jdbc sampler?

Tags: syntax, jmeter

It appears that Jmeter's  jdbc sampler only want to save stuff as String.
In a later step I need this value as an Int-value. But syntax gets wrong all the time for me... tried converting it in beanshell script, but got syntax errors there too... x)

Example:

Sampler 1
JDBC: `SELECT number from table`
variable names:  `number1`
Handle resultset: `String`

Sampler 2
JDBC: `Select * from table2 where number = '{$number1}'`
`ERROR SQLCODE=-420`

Any ideas? :D

Answer (score 0):

[JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html) are always Strings (unless you explicitly call [vars.putObject()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#putObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) function in a script)

With regards to your question itself, when you define a **Prepared Select Statement** in the JDBC Request and properly populate "Parameter values" and "Parameter types" fields like:

[image]

More information:

- [JDBC - Data Types](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-data-types.htm)
- [Using Prepared Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Also with regards to your Beanshell approach, altough it's not applicable here at all, be informed that [starting from JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 test elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting mainly for performance reasons, see [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more details.